# How can I replicate this material animation?

Tags: android, animation

By opening the stock, material clock app, you can see different "alarm tiles". If you click one of them, it elevates and resizes. I don't know about any built-in animation what is able to achieve this, but there must be one. Do you know which one?

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me which app it is so I can really see it ?

Comment: If you open up an emulator, the default clock application will be this. (See the image.) There is also an app, called "CLock Lollipop" in the Play Store, which is almost the same.